# Beijing airport to Great Wall of China in six hours?

Tags: transit, beijing, great-wall-of-china

Is it possible to do a round trip to Great Wall of China within a transit time of six hours? Namely, from 2pm to 8pm on a working day.

Comment: Here is a [tripadvisor post](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294212-i2147-k7199917-How_to_travel_from_Beijing_Capital_Airport_to_Great_Wall-Beijing.html) that might be of your interest.

Comment: I think that it us somewhere between very difficult and impossible.  You would certainly need to have it planned in advance.  If you just get out of the airport with nothing arranged then I think that you have no chance.  What sort of visa do you have?  It is a few years since I was there but the visa on arrival may be valid only within Beijing and the Wall is not in Beijing.  Why not stay a day or two or three?  The Wall needs a whole day to see it well.  There is lots more to see as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. For this I wouldn't bother with trains - a prebooked ride from airport to Badaling would take 1-2 hours. This gives you two hours to see the Wall - which is not much, but you can still take a cable car up, and then walk down to the exit. You can do this in an hour if you're in a good shape and have good walking shoes.

You should prebook your ride with one of many car hire companies, agree on schedule, destination and price. Do not take taxis, and do not expect the taxi drivers to speak any English.

Comment: Immigration there was always fast to me. Never had to wait more than 10-15 minutes. Driver, of course, need to be prearranged. And yes, there's risk involved, and yes, it is rushing, but my understanding is that a person asking this question understands both of those aspects.